# PythonAnyWhere.com and github repo have different sql database information

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, pythonanywhere

My project is deployed in PythonAnyWhere.com and at the same time in Github, and for some reason, when I look at the sqlite database file and check the datas saved inside, I find that the 2 (github and PythonAnyWhere) files have different datas store in them , anyone know why ? and how to transfer the correct datas from PythonAnywhere to github repo

Comment: How can we POSSIBLY answer this question, without seeing any code or any data?  YOU need to debug this by tracing through the code.

Comment: Why do you expect/how do you ensure both DB files are in sync?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.